# how to select the ages which are less than or greater than from drop down in grails and groovy

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, grails, groovy

I have a requirement that should have one drop down containing some conditions on age.
like less than 10days,between 10 to 30 days,between 1 month to 3 months,between 4 month to 12 months,between 1yr to 2 yr.

I have domain class containing one property age(integer).and i am calculating age form dob to current date and storing in DB.I have search criteria to search based on age in search page,So  how can i display these condition vales in drop down and when i select one option how to display the result based on age.

presently i am displaying all ages in drop down form the DB, please find the code and help me in doing this, if its not clear please write the comments so that i can explain u.

this is my drop down contaning all dobs

```
 <td><span id="availableAge" ></span></td>
```

This is my script to get dobs from controller with an ajax call

```
 function generateAge(data){
        var list ="<select style='width:100px' id='age' name='age'><option value=''>-Select-</option>";
        var opt;    
            for(var i=0; i<data.ageDetails.length; i++){
                opt = "<option value="+data.ageDetails[i].age+">";
                opt = opt+data.ageDetails[i].age;
                opt = opt+"</option>";  
                list = list+opt;                
            }           
        list = list+"</select>";
        var listObj = document.getElementById("availableAge");
        if(listObj){
            listObj.innerHTML = list;
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a bad idea to store age in DB, as it changes all the time - better stick with DOB.

As the option set is fixed, make something like an `enum` for it, use its `values()` to render a `select`

`enum AgeCriteriaEnum { NONE, LESS_THAN_10, BETWEEN_10_AND_30, ... so on }`

and just do a `switch()` like:

```
AgeCriteriaEnum ageEnum = AgeCriteriaEnum.valueOf(params.ageEnum)
Date today = new Date()

Patient.withCriteria {
  switch(ageEnum) {
    case AgeCriteriaEnum.NONE: 
      break;
    case AgeCriteriaEnum.LESS_THAN_10: 
      ge('dob', today-10)
      break;
    case AgeCriteriaEnum.BETWEEN_10_AND_30: 
      lt('dob', today-10)
      ge('dob', today-30)
      break;
      //... so on
  }
}
```